# How to Calculate differential Count

Tags: vba, ms-access

We are coming across a clinical project in MS Access where we have to calculate DLC. The method is :

```
Type.          Value Range
```

1. Neutrophils.      40 - 80
2. Lymphocytes.      20 - 40
3. Eosinophils.      02 - 08
4. Monocytes.        01 - 03
5. Basophils.        00 - 02

In any case total of all 5 types has to be 100

The question is how can we automate the process in VBA so that each value falls within avove range and total is always 100. The result will be stored in a table.

Example is

1. N = 65
2. L = 25
3. E = 06
4. M = 03
5. B = 01

---

Total= 100

Nothing seems to work

Comment: I don't understand the question. Where do the values come from? Sounds to me as if they are laboratory test results? What do you want to automate there?

Comment: They are demo values where we have to repeatedly change values to demonstrate/teach various situations

Comment: So you make up the values, they need to be in the given ranges and should sum up to 100. I guess you need to define for yourself how you expect the program to work. Which of the values are entered manually, which should be "guessed" be the program? What do you expect if you enter 70 + 30 for the first two values? Programming is not the issue, the rules are.

Comment: It should go like this : N = Random number between 40 - 80, L = Random Number between 20 - 40 and so on till all values are obtained between said range. The total of all values should add to 100

Comment: Int ((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound).  All values are calculated and nothing is entered. These can be any Random values aggregating to 100 on press of a button. The problem is only aggregating all values to 100.

Comment: It might take quite a while to generate 5 random numbers which add exactly to 100...  One of those numbers should likely be created by adding the other 4 and subtracting from 100.  Suggest you do that for Neutrophils.

Comment: As a method of calculating, I would suggest starting with (5) Basophils, and working backwards to generate the other values. This would leave (1) Neutrophils having a variable cap. If you start with Neutrophils and generate 80, then what happens, as the min of the other 4 must be 23?

Comment: Note that for a valid solution, the minimum value for N is 47 (because the maximum for all other values is 53), and the maximum value for N is 77 (because the minimum for all others is 23)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key point is that you need to generate values that are not only within the defined range, they must be also in a range where it is possible to create a valid solution for the not yet defined values.

As I already wrote as a comment, the value of N needs to be within the range of 47 and 77. If it is below 47, the following 4 values cannot fill the gap to 100 even if they would be set to their allowed max value. If it is above 77, the following 4 values will always exceed 100, even if they would be set to their allowed min value.

This logic continues for the following values: Assuming we choose 65 for N. The remaining 4 values must add up to 35. The minimum that can be reached by the last 3 values is 3, the maximum is 13. The value for L must be at least 35-13=22 and at max 35-3=32, and so on.

Have a look to the following code: It follows the logic that it calculates the minimal and maximal possible values so that the target of 100 can be reached and creates a value within that range.

```
Sub getABloodySolution()
    Dim wbcTypes, minValues, maxValues, values
    wbcTypes = Array("N", "L", "E", "M", "B")
    minValues = Array(40, 20, 2, 1, 0)
    maxValues = Array(80, 40, 8, 3, 2)
    values = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

    Dim goal As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    goal = 100
    For i = LBound(wbcTypes) To UBound(wbcTypes)
        ' Calculate Minimum and Maximum that can be reached by the following values
        Dim minPossible As Long, maxPossible As Long
        minPossible = 0
        maxPossible = 0
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(wbcTypes)
            minPossible = minPossible + minValues(j)
            maxPossible = maxPossible + maxValues(j)
        Next j
        
        ' Calculate the Range for the random value
        Dim minVal As Long, maxVal As Long
        minVal = minValues(i)
        maxVal = maxValues(i)
        If goal - minPossible < maxVal Then maxVal = goal - minPossible
        If goal - maxPossible > minVal Then minVal = goal - maxPossible
        
        ' Create random value 
        values(i) = Int((maxVal - minVal + 1) * Rnd + minVal)
        Debug.Print wbcTypes(i) & "=" & values(i), "Remaining=" & goal, "Min=" & minVal, "Max=" & maxVal
        goal = goal - values(i)  ' Reduce that value from goal for the remaining values
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked beautifully! Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this method:

1. Fill an array with test values
2. Pass this to my function `RoundSum` and set it to scale the sum to 100
3. Read the array returned

If some value fall outside its range, repeat.

`RoundSum` and its helper functions (too much code to post here) are for download at **GitHub**: [VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round#rounding-a-series-of-numbers-to-a-sum).

Full documentation is here: [Round elements of a sum to match a total](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/31683/Round-elements-of-a-sum-to-match-a-total.html?preview=175fPXbOqV8%3D)